# User accepted an answer that didn't help them

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, accepted-answer

The poster of the question admitted that this answer didn't solve their problem yet they have accepted it as an answer...

The question is here: [WCF service returning 404 on method reqests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240217/wcf-service-returning-404-on-method-reqests)

The question-asker comments: "Though this did not solve my issue, most of these are the best bet for anyone searching for a solution. Enjoy the bounty. :)"

I think this is just inappropriate. If there wasn't a useful answer then you don't just pick up a random answer and mark it as the accepted answer.

My question boils down to whether this should be moderated? Or the asker are completely free here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users are free to accept whatever answer they feel useful (or really any other reason - "helped the most" is very broad definition of acceptance mark).

This particular acceptance was presumably done to assign bounty rather than original "helped me the most". If user did not assign bounty to  particular answer bounty would be assigned automatically and sometimes it would go to answer that is not the best among eligible once from the point of view of owner of the bounty. OP could have assigned bounty separately but for some reason decided not to.

---

<sub>Bounty rules - https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty</sub>

Comment: I assume one can't 'cancel' a bounty (aside from that looking bad)?

Comment: @Mzn in rare cases moderators can cancel bounty (if one flags with *very* good reason), otherwise - no, there is no way to cancel bounty and it will be awarded on a question automatically if no action is taken.